# Nodejs application not connecting Redis in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose

I have a `Nodejs` application which connects to a `Redis` instance. I am using `docker-compose` for the setup, and running `docker-compose up`. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
# Specify docker-compose version.
version: '3'

# Define the services/containers to be run.
services:

  express:
    build: .
    container_name: node-app
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - redis-cache

  redis-cache:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm ci

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ “npm”, “start” ] // Also tried CMD [ “node”, “index.js” ]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
redis-cache_1  | 1:M 19 Jan 2021 04:23:49.411 * Ready to accept connections
node-app | sh: “start”: unknown operand
node-app exited with code 2
```

So, I went inside the container and manually ran `npm start`. The Nodejs started successfully but gave the following error while connecting Redis:

```
Error: Redis connection to redis-cache:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis-cache
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'redis-cache'
}
```

Also tried `node index.js` but still got the same error. This is how I am connecting to my `Redis` instance in my `Nodejs` application:

```
const client = redis.createClient({host: 'redis-cache', port: 6379});
```

I have tried various answers on `StackOverflow` as well as various other sites, but none works for me. Please help !

Comment: This is strange. Try `docker-compose down` to remove containers then `docker-compose up` again. One possible reason for the error is different networks between containers and these two commands should fix it. If it won't fix the problem try using `docker-compose exec express sh` to get into the container's shell. Then try to ping redis or otherwise check DNS lookup.

Comment: Double-checking, that error message is the `docker-compose logs express` output, and not the result of trying to run the same code a different way?

Comment: What command are you using to run docker-compose?

Comment: @anemyte I tried docker-compose down and up. Didn't work. Went into container's shell and the error is  `ERROR: No container found for express_1`. The container startup is failing and giving the error `sh: “start”: unknown operand`.

Comment: @DavidMaze The container was not starting and was giving `sh: “start”: unknown operand`, so I went inside the container and manually ran `npm start`. Nodejs started and then threw this error while connecting Redis.

Comment: @Danizavtz i have update the question to give more info

Comment: Can you try to run docker-compose with --build flag. command: `docker-compose up --build`. I'm guessing it could be some local cache from old generated images in docker.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your Dockerfile?  The "unknown operand" error would be related to something in there.  If the main container process is failing, what command are you running to get a shell in the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze Added my dockerfile.

Comment: @Danizavtz Getting same error while running `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: Do you have "plain" quotes `CMD [ "npm", "start" ]` or "curly" quotes `CMD [ “npm”, “start” ]`?  If you have the "curly" quotes, it's not a valid JSON array, and Docker will fall back to processing the command as a shell command `sh -c '[ “npm”, “start” ]'` which will lead to that error.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you, this was the error ! I changed the quotes and it works now.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you post as an answer? It can help others.